# Dropping rows with NaN values on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

not sure what I am missing. I am trying to drop the all rows with NaN/empty values on one of the columns. Thanks.

```py
df.dropna(how='all', subset=['column_one', 'column_two'], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: If it's either column shouldn't it be how='any' rather than how='all'?

Comment: try changing how='any'

Comment: Could you provide simple example (what does your DF looks like and what is the expected output)? I guess others are right and you will need to use `how="any"` but it's hard to say when we do not know any other details.

Comment: Thank you Norie, Ayesha and Nerxis. how="any" was the solution and it worked well.